# Rails reports can't find a column that is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am currently trying to do a complicated `WHERE` search on a table using Rails, the trouble is I get the error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "email" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "bans".* FROM "bans"  WHERE (Email='' AND IP='' AND (...
                                        ^
: SELECT "bans".* FROM "bans"  WHERE (Email='' AND IP='' AND (Username='NULL' ))
```

And I know that column actually exists, and doing a `rails dbconsole` gives me the following:

```
Jungle=> select * from bans;
 id | Username | IP | Email | Reason | Length | created_at | updated_at 
----+----------+----+-------+--------+--------+------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

So this is definatly in the database, has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: Are you using postgres with case-sensitive column names?

Comment: Case is exactly the same though in the SQL and the table

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I guess it is in one place, although the column it says is missing is in all lower.

Comment: @DaveNewton: That's because PostgreSQL normalizes identifiers to lower case (even though the standard says upper case).

Comment: @muistooshort Ah, gotcha. I figured it was that somehow, but +1 for the great answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQL column names are case insensitive unless quoted, the standard says that identifiers should be normalized to upper case but [PostgreSQL normalizes to lower case](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers `FOO`, `foo`, and `"foo"` are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but `"Foo"` and `"FOO"` are different from these three and each other. (The folding of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper case. Thus, `foo` should be equivalent to `"FOO"` not `"foo"` according to the standard. If you want to write portable applications you are advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it.)

You're referencing `Email` in your SQL:

```
SELECT "bans".* FROM "bans"  WHERE (Email='' ...
```

but PostgreSQL is complaining about `email`:

```
column "email" does not exist
```

Your unquoted `Email` is being treated as `email` because PostgreSQL normalizes identifiers to lower case. Sounds like you created the columns with capitalized names by double quoting them:

```
create table "bans" (
    "Email" varchar(...)
    ...
)
```

or by using `:Email` to identify the column in a migration. If you quote a column name when it is created, then it is not normalized to lower case (or upper case in the SQL standard case) and you'll have to double quote it and match the case forever:

```
SELECT "bans".* FROM "bans"  WHERE ("Email"='' ...
```

Once you fix `Email`, you'll have the same problem with `IP`, `Username`, `Reason`, and `Length`: you'll have to double quote them all in any SQL that references them.

The best practise is to use lower case column and table names so that you don't have to worry about quoting things all the time. I'd recommend that you fix your table to have lower case column names.

---

As an aside, your `'NULL'` string literal:

```
SELECT "bans".* FROM "bans"  WHERE (Email='' AND IP='' AND (Username='NULL' ))
-- -------------------->------------------>---------->---------------^^^^^^
```

looks odd, are you sure that you don't mean `"Username" is null`? The `'NULL'` string literal and the NULL value are entirely different things and you can't use `=` or `!=` to compare things against NULL, you have to use [`is null`, `is not null`, `is distinct from`, or `is not distinct from`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html) (depending on your intent) when NULLs might be in play.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem, I just used the standard rails generate model etc, This means I have to rewrite and reprint my whole DB design doc now however! Thankyou anyway for your help.

Comment: @nekosune: Perhaps the guilt from killing all those trees will help you avoid this mistake in the future :)

Comment: I feel sorry for the trees yes, even more so for the work it will take to get the change all approved before I can start, but the extra work caused by this odd behaviour needs it.

Comment: Following the conventions of rails will indeed prevent a lot of pain that you would otherwise find with mixed case names.

Comment: I was actually unaware of rails conventions regarding this, I really need to actually spend more time learning the basics.

Comment: This is actually the intersection of a PostgreSQL best practice (unquoted lower case identifiers) and a Ruby/Rails convention (lower case names with word separated by underscores).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're error is from a test database but if so try `rake db:test:prepare`.

In general, be aware that you have 3 databases - Test, Development, Production. So it's easy to get them mixed up and check the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here,

but as `mu-is-too-short` said, PostgreSql can be told to 
search with case sensitivity on columns names.

So by implemented this code I managed to bypass the same error that you're facing:

```
Transaction.find(:all,:conditions => ["(date between ?  and ?) AND \"Membership_id\" = ?", Time.now.at_beginning_of_month,  Time.now.end_of_month,membership.id])
```

Noticed the **\"** sign srrounding the column name? Well.. as annoying as it is, that's the fix to this problem.