# ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "weeknumber" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue using the activeRecord order function with PG database on heroku.  I have the following code which is working just fine currently, except for the fact that occasionally the records get out of the order I want them. So, I tried using the .order function on the database and now I get the PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR.  If I remove the .order function it works again.

Nothing is changed in either the models or the database when it breaks. It's only adding the .order function to try and control the ordering of the database records.

Also, it works just fine in development on an sqlite3 database.

Here is the code that works:

```
1 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
2   <tr>
3     <td></td>
4     <% @pool.weeks.each do |week| %>
5       <td class="entry-header">
6         <%= "Week #{week.weekNumber}" %> 
7       </td>
8     <% end %>
9   </tr>
```

Here is the change that causes it to break:

```
Change line 4 from this:
   4     <% @pool.weeks.each do |week| %>
to this:
   4     <% @pool.weeks.order("weekNumber ASC").each do |week| %>
```

As soon as I add the .order function it breaks on heroku with the following errors:

```
app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "weeknumber" does not exist
app[web.1]:     2:   <tr>
app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...M "weeks"  WHERE "weeks"."pool_id" = $1  ORDER BY weekNumber...
app[web.1]: : SELECT "weeks".* FROM "weeks"  WHERE "weeks"."pool_id" = $1  ORDER BY weekNumber ASC):
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     1: <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
app[web.1]:     4:     <% @pool.weeks.order("weekNumber ASC").each do |week| %>
app[web.1]:     3:     <td></td>
app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...M "weeks"  WHERE "weeks"."pool_id" = $1  ORDER BY weekNumber...
app[web.1]:     5:       <td class="entry-header">
app[web.1]:   app/views/pools/_show_board.html.erb:4:in   `_app_views_pools__show_board_html_erb___2914673273129495301_70355170381800'
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     3:     <td></td>
app[web.1]:   app/views/pools/show.html.erb:28:in `_app_views_pools_show_html_erb__33868809623974782_70355169938300'
app[web.1]:     6:         <%= "Week #{week.weekNumber}" %>
app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "weeknumber" does not exist
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     7:       </td>
app[web.1]: : SELECT "weeks".* FROM "weeks"  WHERE "weeks"."pool_id" = $1  ORDER BY weekNumber ASC):
app[web.1]:   app/views/pools/_show_board.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_pools__show_board_html_erb___2914673273129495301_70355170381800'
app[web.1]:     2:   <tr>
app[web.1]:     5:       <td class="entry-header">
app[web.1]:   app/views/pools/show.html.erb:28:in `_app_views_pools_show_html_erb__33868809623974782_70355169938300'
app[web.1]:     7:       </td>
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:                                                              ^
app[web.1]:     1: <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
app[web.1]:     4:     <% @pool.weeks.order("weekNumber ASC").each do |week| %>
app[web.1]:     6:         <%= "Week #{week.weekNumber}" %>
app[web.1]:
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pools/1 host=fb-pools.herokuapp.com fwd="76.250.116.65" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=142ms status=500 bytes=643
heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
```

Nothing was changed in the database. The only change is adding the .order function. I'm guessing something is missing in my migration but I'm not sure what.

Here is the migration file associated with the weeks model:

```
class CreateWeeks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :weeks do |t|
      t.integer :state
      t.integer :pool_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddWeekNumberToWeeks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :weeks, :weekNumber, :integer
  end
end
```

Here are the Pool and Week models:

```
class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base

  POOL_TYPES = { PickEm: 0, PickEmSpread: 1, Survivor: 2, SUP: 3 }

  has_many :users, through: :pool_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pool_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :weeks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy

  # Make sure protected fields aren't updated after a week has been created on the pool
  validate :checkUpdateFields, on: :update

  attr_accessor :password

  validates :name,     presence:   true,
                       length:      { :maximum => 30 },
                       uniqueness:  { :case_sensitive => false }
  validates :poolType, inclusion:   { in: 0..3 }
  validates :allowMulti, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
  validates :isPublic, inclusion:   { in: [true, false] }

  ...   

end

class Week < ActiveRecord::Base

  STATES = { Pend: 0, Open: 1, Closed: 2, Final: 3 }

  belongs_to :pool
  has_many   :games, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :picks, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :games

  ...

end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails reports can't find a column that is there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628917/rails-reports-cant-find-a-column-that-is-there)

Comment: @ZachKemp: That's exactly the problem, they'll have to say things like `.order('"weekNumber" ASC')` with column names like those. Or create the column as `:week_number` so that no one has to worry about it.

Comment: It does look like I'm having the same issue. However, the solution to that issues was to redo all of the database and remove the mixed case table entries.  Unfortunately I cannot redo my tables at this time as the application is live.  So, how can I get the order() function to work with this mixed case issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your column name as `weekNumber` but ActiveRecord isn't respecting the case-sensitivity, so is looking for a column called `weeknumber`.

Change your column name to `week_number` and update your order to `week_number` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Delimit CamelCase names with a double quotes.

FROM THIS:

```
<% @pool.weeks.order("weekNumber ASC").each do |week| %>
```

TO THIS

```
<% @pool.weeks.order("\"weekNumber\" ASC").each do |week| %>
```