# rails collection_select do not set foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, belongs-to

I have a problem with collection_select that do not set the foreign key.

I am working with rails over a legacy database. So I need to 'translate' the names.

I have these classes:

```
class Graos::Preco < ActiveRecord::Base
  # translate to legacy database
  self.table_name  = 'GRAOPreco'
  self.primary_key = 'IDPreco'

  # relacionamentos
  belongs_to :Serie,
    :class_name  => 'Public::Serie',
    :foreign_key => 'IDSerie' 
end


class Public::Serie < ActiveRecord::Base
    # translate to legacy database
    self.table_name  = 'GERSerie'
    self.primary_key = 'IDSerie'

    # relacionamentos
    has_many :Precos,
        foreign_key:    'IDSerie',
        class_name:     'Graos::Preco'
end
```

and,

```
            <%= collection_select(:Serie, :IDSerie, Public::Serie.graos_soja, :IDSerie, :SerieAcesso, { prompt: "Selecione uma Série" }, { class: "span6" }) %>
```

When submit the form, the Serie attribute is set, but the foreign key IDSerie is not...

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

2 ideas:

1) There might be a problem if DB is PostgreSQL, which is case sensitive and [normalizes to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628917/rails-reports-cant-find-a-column-that-is-there).

2) You use `:IDSerie` in `collection_select` twice, while [usually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907867/can-someone-explain-collection-select-to-me-in-clear-simple-terms) foreign key -> primary key are used, yielding `:IDSerie,..,:IDPreco` instead of `:IDSerie,..,:IDSerie`

Hope it helps.