# Date compare with rails 4 + pg column not existe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, pg

Got a strange problem in my app.

I need to compare a date column.

If I try

```
testing =  Accessibility.where(:DatAccsBegn => Date.today)
```

it works fine, but I need to do a <= So if I try

```
testing =  Accessibility.where("DatAccsBegn <= ?", Date.today)
```

Got an error "column "dataccsbegn" does not exist"

Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628917/rails-reports-cant-find-a-column-that-is-there

Comment: Unless you are working with a legacy database which can't be changed, your life will be a lot easier if you rename your columns to "dat_accs_begn",  etc, or even "date_access_began", if you feel like sparing a few extra characters to make them actual readable words (which is always nicer).

Comment: Quoting DatAccsBegn return no error, but no results to ans there is results in database.

Comment: try this i hope this will work `testing = Accessibility.where("DatAccsBegn <= '#{Date.today}'")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I renamed all column in my database.

With Postgreql, column are case insensitive, except if they are quoted, but if you quote, you lose column type.

So, i renamed my column to respect standards like dat_accs_begn and it works.